# Problemas com o BackSpace no TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox

Tenho um projeto para montar uma textbox que só incluiria horas e minutos (Com o DateTimerPicker, da pra fazer tranquilo, contudo precisa clickar em outro campo para alterar dados, e eu achei isso muito ruim para o cliente...

Dessa forma programei um TextBox para que colocasse um ":" para defini-lo bonitinho, sem nenhum problemas.

**Porém**, ao fazer-lo aceitar somente números me bloqueia de usar o backspace (ASCII - 8)...

```
private void txtHoraMarcada_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox mascara = sender as TextBox;
            if (mascara.Text.Length == 2)
            {
                mascara.Text += ":";
                txtHoraMarcada.SelectionStart = 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Tem alguma coisa a ver usar o evento de Keypress para o KeyDown nessa ocasião??

Só precisava liberar para apagar em vez de ter que selecionar tudo para dar Del e escrever novamente, Obrigado!

Comment: melhor usar um `maskedtextbox` não ?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que poderia usar um `MaskedTextBox` que te atenderia melhor nessa situação. Mas respondendo à questão:

Basta você alterar o `if`. Utilizei a seguinte condição:

> Se o caractere for um número, ou um controle (backspace, delete, etc...) executo sua lógica, caso contrário o evento é manipulado (não faz nada).

```
private void txtHoraMarcada_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        TextBox mascara = sender as TextBox;
        if (mascara.Text.Length == 2)
        {
            mascara.Text += ":";
            txtHoraMarcada.SelectionStart = 3;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

> Ps.: Não analisei sua lógica para aplicar a máscara, apenas a parte do if. E, se quiser checar se foi pressionado apenas o backspace, poderia fazer assim:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)8)
{
   //foi pressionado backspace
}
```

Para mais códigos dos caracteres, veja a tabela ASCII:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Cassiani não se esqueça de marcar como resposta se resolveu seu problema. Se tiver alguma dúvida sobre a comunidade visite o tour: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour